# Imported member fails to create Mongoose model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ecmascript-6

When either of the `model` or `Schema` members of the `mongoose` module are imported and used to create a model, the process fails. For example, the code below:

**sample.model.js**

```
import { model } from 'mongoose'
import { Schema } from 'mongoose'

let sampleSchema = Schema({
  sampleName: String
})

export default model('Sample', sampleSchema)
```

reports this error in the console:

```
  if (!this.modelSchemas[name]) {
           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'modelSchemas' of undefined
```

However, when the `mongoose` module was imported and the members used, the model was created successfully. The code block that worked is shown below:

**sample.model.js**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

let sampleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  sampleName: String
})

export default mongoose.model('Sample', sampleSchema)
```

The imported members from the first code sample were inspected and proven to be correct.

Why did the member imports fail to create the model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not going to work due to implementation of mongoose. Please see details below. https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3768#issuecomment-178313121